# Requires numeric/complex matric/vector argument

Tags: r, regression, breakpoints

So I have a large data set that I have imported and split up. I've made sure to attach everything and tried to run a code to determine the number of breakpoints using AIC.

```
    rm(list=ls())
    library(Matching)
    library(segmented)
    
    dinosaurs=read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/NEW PLOTS FOR DINOS/centrum_input_fin.csv")
    
    attach(dinosaurs)
    names(dinosaurs)
    dino_names <- names(dinosaurs)
    
    #NEED TO EXPORT FILES (EXPORT THE ALL_DATA_PLUS_SORTED OUT)
    all_data_plus_sorted<-NULL
    for(j in 1:length(dino_names))
    {
      with_gaps<-eval(parse(text = dino_names[j]))
      gaps <- which(is.na(with_gaps))
      non_gaps <-which(1:length(with_gaps) %in%gaps==FALSE)
      sorted_without_gaps <- sort(with_gaps[!is.na(with_gaps)],decreasing=TRUE)
      ordered_with_gaps<-rep(NA,length(with_gaps))
      for(k in 1:length(non_gaps))
      {
        ordered_with_gaps[non_gaps[k]] <- sorted_without_gaps[k]
      }
      to_export<-cbind(with_gaps,ordered_with_gaps)
      colnames(to_export)<-c(paste(dino_names[j],"_actual_with_gaps",sep=""),paste(dino_names[j],"_ordered_with_gaps",sep=""))
      all_data_plus_sorted<- cbind(all_data_plus_sorted,to_export)
    }
    
    all_data_plus_sorted
    attach(as.data.frame(all_data_plus_sorted))
    print(dinosaurs)
    
    detach(as.data.frame(all_data_plus_sorted))
    detach(dinosaurs)
    
    #split species
    Dyoplosaurus_acutosquameus_ROM734 <- Dyoplosaurus_acutosquameus_ROM734[!is.na(Dyoplosaurus_acutosquameus_ROM734)]
    Staurikosaurus_pricei <- Staurikosaurus_pricei[!is.na(Staurikosaurus_pricei)]
    Opistocoelocaudia_skarzynskii <- Opistocoelocaudia_skarzynskii[!is.na(Opistocoelocaudia_skarzynskii)]
    Stegosaurus_stenops._NHMUKPVR36730 <- Stegosaurus_stenops._NHMUKPVR36730[!is.na(Stegosaurus_stenops._NHMUKPVR36730)]
    Giraffatitan_brancai <- Giraffatitan_brancai[!is.na(Giraffatitan_brancai)]
    Camptosaurus <- Camptosaurus[!is.na(Camptosaurus)]
    Camptosaurus_prestwichii <- Camptosaurus_prestwichii[!is.na(Camptosaurus_prestwichii)]
    A_greppini <- A_greppini[!is.na(A_greppini)]
    Astrophocaudia_slaughteri_SMU61732 <- Astrophocaudia_slaughteri_SMU61732[!is.na(Astrophocaudia_slaughteri_SMU61732)]
    Tastavinsaurus_sanzi_gen_MPZ999 <- Tastavinsaurus_sanzi_gen_MPZ999[!is.na(Tastavinsaurus_sanzi_gen_MPZ999)]
    MOZ_Pv1221 <- MOZ_Pv1221[!is.na(MOZ_Pv1221)]
    Mamenchisaurus <- Mamenchisaurus[!is.na(Mamenchisaurus)]
    Bromtosaurus_CMNo3018 <- Bromtosaurus_CMNo3018[!is.na(Bromtosaurus_CMNo3018)]
    Lufengosaurus_Hueni <- Lufengosaurus_Hueni[!is.na(Lufengosaurus_Hueni)]
    Mamenchisaurus_hochuanensi <- Mamenchisaurus_hochuanensi[!is.na(Mamenchisaurus_hochuanensi)]
    Spinosaurus_FSACKK11888 <- Spinosaurus_FSACKK11888[!is.na(Spinosaurus_FSACKK11888)]
    Buitreraptor_MPCNPV370 <- Buitreraptor_MPCNPV370[!is.na(Buitreraptor_MPCNPV370)]
    Buitreraptor_MPCA245 <- Buitreraptor_MPCA245[!is.na(Buitreraptor_MPCA245)]
    Huabeisaurus_allocotus_HBV20001 <- Huabeisaurus_allocotus_HBV20001[!is.na(Huabeisaurus_allocotus_HBV20001)]
    Tethyshadros_insularis_SC57021 <- Tethyshadros_insularis_SC57021[!is.na(Tethyshadros_insularis_SC57021)]
    Compsognathus_longipes_CNJ79 <- Compsognathus_longipes_CNJ79[!is.na(Compsognathus_longipes_CNJ79)]
    Archaeopteryx12 <- Archaeopteryx12[!is.na(Archaeopteryx12)]
    Sinosauropteryx_NIGP127586 <- Sinosauropteryx_NIGP127586[!is.na(Sinosauropteryx_NIGP127586)]
    Sinosauropteryx_NIGP_127587 <- Sinosauropteryx_NIGP_127587[!is.na(Sinosauropteryx_NIGP_127587)]
    Tetonosaurus_tilletti_AMNH3040 <- Tetonosaurus_tilletti_AMNH3040[!is.na(Tetonosaurus_tilletti_AMNH3040)]
    Bambiraptor_feinbergi_FIP001 <- Bambiraptor_feinbergi_FIP001[!is.na(Bambiraptor_feinbergi_FIP001)]
    Seimosaurus.halli_NMMNH3690 <- Seimosaurus.halli_NMMNH3690[!is.na(Seimosaurus.halli_NMMNH3690)]
    Diluvicursor_pickeringi_NMVP221080 <- Diluvicursor_pickeringi_NMVP221080[!is.na(Diluvicursor_pickeringi_NMVP221080)]
    Zhejiungosuurus_lishuiensis_ZMNHM8718 <- Zhejiungosuurus_lishuiensis_ZMNHM8718[!is.na(Zhejiungosuurus_lishuiensis_ZMNHM8718)]
    Tianyulong_confuciusi_STMN.263 <- Tianyulong_confuciusi_STMN.263[!is.na(Tianyulong_confuciusi_STMN.263)]
    Lusotitan_atalaiensis <- Lusotitan_atalaiensis[!is.na(Lusotitan_atalaiensis)]
    Nemegtonykus_citus_MPCD100203 <- Nemegtonykus_citus_MPCD100203[!is.na(Nemegtonykus_citus_MPCD100203)]
    Elaphrosaurus_bambergi_MBR4960 <- Elaphrosaurus_bambergi_MBR4960[!is.na(Elaphrosaurus_bambergi_MBR4960)]
    Nomingia_gobiensis_GIN100119 <- Nomingia_gobiensis_GIN100119[!is.na(Nomingia_gobiensis_GIN100119)]
    Nomingia_gobiensis_MPCD100119 <- Nomingia_gobiensis_MPCD100119[!is.na(Nomingia_gobiensis_MPCD100119)]
    Chirostenotes_pergracilis <- Chirostenotes_pergracilis[!is.na(Chirostenotes_pergracilis)]
    Seismosaurus_hallorum_NMMNHP3690 <- Seismosaurus_hallorum_NMMNHP3690[!is.na(Seismosaurus_hallorum_NMMNHP3690)]
    Heterodontosaurus_tucki_SAMPKK1332 <- Heterodontosaurus_tucki_SAMPKK1332[!is.na(Heterodontosaurus_tucki_SAMPKK1332)]
    Jianianhualong_tengi_DLXH1218 <- Jianianhualong_tengi_DLXH1218[!is.na(Jianianhualong_tengi_DLXH1218)]
    Yinlong_downsi_IVPPV18685 <- Yinlong_downsi_IVPPV18685[!is.na(Yinlong_downsi_IVPPV18685)]
    Neimongosaurus_yangi_LHV0001 <- Neimongosaurus_yangi_LHV0001[!is.na(Neimongosaurus_yangi_LHV0001)]
    Magnapaulia_laticaudus_LACM17715 <- Magnapaulia_laticaudus_LACM17715[!is.na(Magnapaulia_laticaudus_LACM17715)] 
    Ouranosaurus_nigeriensis <- Ouranosaurus_nigeriensis[!is.na(Ouranosaurus_nigeriensis)]
    Dreadnoughtus_schrani_MPMPV1156 <- Dreadnoughtus_schrani_MPMPV1156[!is.na(Dreadnoughtus_schrani_MPMPV1156)]
    Pectodens_zhenyuensis_IVPPV18578 <- Pectodens_zhenyuensis_IVPPV18578[!is.na(Pectodens_zhenyuensis_IVPPV18578)]
    Dilophosaurus_wetherilli <- Dilophosaurus_wetherilli[!is.na(Dilophosaurus_wetherilli)]
    Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100746 <- Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100746[!is.na(Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100746)]
    Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100755 <- Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100755[!is.na(Gobihadros_mongoliensis_MPCD100755)]
    Auroraceratops_rugosus_GJ07913 <- Auroraceratops_rugosus_GJ07913[!is.na(Auroraceratops_rugosus_GJ07913)]
    Patagotitan_mayorum_MPEFPV <- Patagotitan_mayorum_MPEFPV[!is.na(Patagotitan_mayorum_MPEFPV)]
    Eoraptor_lunensi_PVSJ512 <- Eoraptor_lunensi_PVSJ512[!is.na(Eoraptor_lunensi_PVSJ512)]
    Corythosaurus_casuarius <- Corythosaurus_casuarius[!is.na(Corythosaurus_casuarius)]
    Caihong._Juji_PMoLB00175 <- Caihong._Juji_PMoLB00175[!is.na(Caihong._Juji_PMoLB00175)]
    Eosinopteryx_brevipenna_YFGPT5197 <- Eosinopteryx_brevipenna_YFGPT5197[!is.na(Eosinopteryx_brevipenna_YFGPT5197)]
    Rahonavis_ostromi_UA8656 <- Rahonavis_ostromi_UA8656[!is.na(Rahonavis_ostromi_UA8656)]
    Changyuraptor_yangi_HGB016 <- Changyuraptor_yangi_HGB016[!is.na(Changyuraptor_yangi_HGB016)]
    Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_PVL2566 <- Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_PVL2566[!is.na(Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_PVL2566)]
    Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_UNSJ53 <- Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_UNSJ53[!is.na(Herrerasaurus_ischigualastensis_UNSJ53)]
    Ischioceratops_zhuchengensis <- Ischioceratops_zhuchengensis[!is.na(Ischioceratops_zhuchengensis)]
    Koreaceratops_hwaseongensis <- Koreaceratops_hwaseongensis[!is.na(Koreaceratops_hwaseongensis)]
    
    # CHOOSE SAMPLE TO ANALYSE
    #_________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # choose sample
    name_to_test <- "Koreaceratops_hwaseongensis"
    y_val <- eval(parse(text = paste(name_to_test,"_actual_with_gaps",sep="")))
    x_val<-1:length(y_val)
    
    # USE AIC TO DECIDE HOW MANY BREAKS TO USE
    #_________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # extract AIC for models with 1-3 breakpoints
    my_max_it=10
    all_mods<-NULL
    for(h in 1:4)
    {
      mod1<-segmented(lm(y_val~x_val),seg.Z=~x_val,psi=NA,control=seg.control(K=h,quant=TRUE,it.max=my_max_it),model=TRUE,nboot=50) 
      all_mods<-rbind(all_mods,c(h,extractAIC(mod1)[2]))    
    }
    all_mods
    my_K<-subset(all_mods,all_mods[,2]==min(all_mods[,2]))[1]
```

When i run the last section of the code i get the error Error in

```
    crossprod(x, y) : 
      requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Not too sure why because I have put it in a data frame, is it because I'm importing the file incorrectly? Not sure how to fix.

Comment: Please don't put `rm(list = ls())` in your example code. No one wants to run your example and accidentally lose what they were working on.

Comment: I would also suggest running `traceback()` after the error to try to figure out exactly what line of code causes the issue.

Comment: I ran traceback ``` 3: crossprod(XREG, y)
2: segmented.lm(lm(y_val ~ x_val), seg.Z = ~x_val, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K = h, 
       quant = TRUE, it.max = my_max_it), model = TRUE, nboot = 50)
1: segmented(lm(y_val ~ x_val), seg.Z = ~x_val, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K = h, 
       quant = TRUE, it.max = my_max_it), model = TRUE, nboot = 50) ```. It was the line i mentioned earlier im jsut not sure why its not working, because it worked for the previous data set, and i had another data set with the remaining new species, but wouldnt work